# Access to jsp path with .action postfix in struts2

Tags: java, struts2, namespaces

I have a project using `struts 2.1.8`. The project is configured by annotation using `struts2-convention-plugin`. Here is my struts config in web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>struts2Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>  
    <filter-name>struts2Filter</filter-name>  
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>  
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>   
    <filter-name>struts2Filter</filter-name>   
    <url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>   
</filter-mapping>
```

struts.xml:

```
<constant name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" value="borrow-default" />
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators" value="action" />
<constant name="struts.convention.package.locators.basePackage" value="com.abc.action" />
<constant name="struts.convention.result.path" value="/" />
```

A.java:

```
@Namespace("/regist")
public class A extends ActionSupport{
    @Action(value="/a", results = {@Result(location = "/a/test.jsp")})
    public String execute(){
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Here is the problem, I can access the test.jsp in url `http://localhost:8080/a/test.jsp` and `http://localhost:8080/regist/a.action`, but I can still visit the same page in url `http://localhost:8080/a/test.action`. I don't know why this happens, what's wrong in my config or code?

---

I also tried some other url, it seems the namespace doesn't take effect.

Comment: where did you keep your test.jsp file. It should be in WEB-INF folder then only it will be protected.

Comment: @MohanaRaoSV it isn't in WEB-INF folder, I can't change the directory now.

Comment: Why didn't you posted the package name?

Comment: @Roman C The package for class A is com.abc.action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded the struts to 2.3.15.1 and this question disappeared

Answer (score 1):

In web.xml your url pattern is like:

```
<url-pattern>/struts/*</url-pattern>
```

but you are placed jsp and getting it from /a/test.jsp
once check it...